Defining a concept with strict type-checking of method arguments
I have the following:
struct Base {};
struct Derived : public Base {};

struct DualHandler {
  static void handle(Base&) {}
  static void handle(Derived&) {}
};

struct SingleHandler {
  static void handle(Base&) {}
};

I want to define a concept that is satisfied by DualHandler but not by SingleHandler. How can I do this?
My naive attempt is:
template<typename T>
concept IsDualHandler = requires(Base& b, Derived& d) {
     { T::handle(b) };
     { T::handle(d) };
};

But unfortunately, SingleHandler satisfies IsDualHandler, because a Derived& can be passed to any function that expects a Base&.

It seems to me that it's correct that SingleHandler satisfies IsDualHandler, since it can indeed correctly process a Derived, since a Derived "is a" Base by virtue of your class definition. What use case do you have where this wouldn't be correct?

Yes, I understand Derived "is a" Base. I want to detect at compile time whether a given handler class has a specialization for a specific Derived type.

@dshin: Concepts are not for detecting exact types; they're for detecting expressions. That's why they're specified by the validity of expressions rather than by a series of declarations that must exist. C++ function call logic requires that if a type is publicly inherited from another, if a function takes a reference to the base class, it must take a reference to a derived class instance in exactly the same way.

@NicolBolas I understand that concepts are designed for expression-requirements, not type-requirements. But in certain contexts, I want to use them for that which they were not designed for (type-requirements). Certainly, type-requirements are a reasonable want out of concepts; otherwise why do languages like Rust support them for their concept-equivalent? Until c++ provides a nicer mechanism to specify type-requirements of template type parameters, we are forced to find creative workarounds like those supplied in this question's answers.

template<class T>
struct be_exactly {
  template<class U> requires (std::same_as<std::decay_t<T>,std::decay_t<U>>)
  operator U&();
};

this tries to match a function argument only exactly.
template<typename T>
concept IsDualHandler = requires(be_exactly<Base> b, be_exactly<Derived> d) {
  { T::handle(b) };
  { T::handle(d) };
};

this distinguishes them.
Live example.
I don't like it being references hard coded; you can fix that with way too much boilerplate.

Note that class with template <typename T> static void handle(T&) {} won't validate IsDualHandler.
